# django - split project to two servers (due to Cloudflare) without duplicating code

Tags: python, django, architecture, django-rest-framework, cloudflare

I currently have a Django project running on a server behind Cloudflare. However, a number of the apps contain functionality that requires synchronizing data with certain web services. This is a security risk, because these web services may reveal the IP address of my server. Therefore I need a solution to prevent this.

So far I came up two alternatives: using a proxy or splitting the project to two servers. One server responsible for responding to requests through Cloudflare and one server responsible for synchronizing data with other web services. The IP address of the latter server will be exposed to the public, however attacks on this server will not cause the website to be offline. I prefer the second solution, because this will also split the load between two servers.

The problem is that I do not know how I should do this with Django without duplicating code. I know I can re-use apps, but for most of them counts that I, for instance, only need the models and the serializers and not the views etc. How should I solve this? What is the best approach to take? In addition, what is an appropriate naming for the two servers? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a single project that is being split as part of the deployment strategy. So it makes sense to use just a single codebase for it, rather than splitting it into two projects. If that's the case, re-use is a non-issue since both servers are using the same code.

To support multiple deployments, then, you just create two settings files and load the appropriate one on the appropriate server. The degree to which they are different is up to you. If you want to support different views you can use different `ROOT_URLCONF` settings. The `INSTALLED_APPS` can be different, and so forth.